# SQL Server : conversion error when attempting to load 'smallmoney' data into table

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I'm trying to load a CSV file into a table in order to sort the data. However, the `smallmoney` column `BillingRate` (e.g. $203.75) will not convert, with SQL Server producing the following message:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (BillingRate).
>   Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 10

Here is the code I am using in order to do this:

```
 --CREATE TABLE SubData2
 --(
 --RecordID int,
 --SubscriberID int,
 --BillingMonth int,
 --BillingRate smallmoney,
 --Region varchar(255)
 --);

 BULK INSERT Subdata2
 FROM 'C:\Folder\1-caseint.csv'
 WITH 
      (FIRSTROW = 2,
       FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',  --CSV field delimiter
       ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', --Use to shift the control to next row
       ERRORFILE = 'C:\Folder\CaseErrorRows4.csv',
       TABLOCK);
```

A typical line of code in the CSV files looks like:

```
1|0000000001|1|$233.94|"West"
```

Apologies if there are any glaring errors here - I'm new to SQL Server :)

Many thanks in advance,
Tom.

Comment: Well, what **is** in row 2, column 4 ?? **Show us** the content of the CSV file!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - it's a currency value, e.g. $203.75

Comment: A typical row in the CSV file would be:

3|0000000003|1|$208.74|"East"

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this, I've added the code to the main question.

Comment: Can you change the CSV and get rid of the `$` sign? Does it work then??

Comment: I've organised it into columns with the $ removed in the CSV. Could I still upload it to SQL with the columns separated in that way? Would it change the field terminator for example?

Comment: Perhaps, initially, it would be easier to import to value as a `varchar` into a staging table, and then transform the data type into your production table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd.  On a direct insert only the last fails.

```
declare @t table (sm smallmoney);
insert into @t 
values ('$256.6')
insert into @t 
values (244.8);
insert into @t 
values ('12.8');
insert into @t 
values ('$256.5'), ('244.7');
insert into @t 
values ($256.5); 
insert into @t 
values ('$256.5'), (244.7), ('12.12');
select * from @t;
```

Give it a try removing the $ from the data.